# SSL connection error:140770FC

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

This the php code for automatic mail sending.

```
 <?php
   $mailto = $_POST['mail_to'];
   $mailSub = $_POST['mail_sub'];
   $mailMsg = $_POST['mail_msg'];
   require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail ->IsSmtp();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 4;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail ->Port = 587; // or 465
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);
   $mail ->Username = "rajaramkumar96@gmail.com";
   $mail ->Password = "************************";
   $mail ->SetFrom("rajaramkumar96@gmail.com");
   $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
   $mail ->Body = $mailMsg;
   $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

   if(!$mail->Send())
    {
     echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
   else
   {
     echo "Mail Sent";
   }







 ?>
```

after running the code i get this error as followed.

2018-03-08 01:33:32 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
2018-03-08 01:33:33 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol [C:\xampp\htdocs\email\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php line 298]
2018-03-08 01:33:33 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [C:\xampp\htdocs\email\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php line 298]
2018-03-08 01:33:33 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unknown error) [C:\xampp\htdocs\email\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php line 298]
2018-03-08 01:33:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` ssl is dated and that advices is in the link you posted, so maybe read the troubleshooting guide before asking

Answer (score 0):

Use SMTPSecure = 'tls' with port 587.

ssl is 465 (smtps?), but very outdated.